Extract key and identification of a Bitlocker recovery key text file with python
I tried to extract and save the Identifier (Bezeichner) and the Key (Wiederherstellungsschlüssel) by defining a regular expression in python. I need it to work regardless of the language of the text.
The Bitlocker recovery key file .txt looks like this:
Wiederherstellungsschlüssel für die BitLocker-Laufwerkverschlüsselung 

Um zu überprüfen, ob es sich um den richtigen Wiederherstellungsschlüssel handelt, vergleichen Sie den Beginn des folgenden Bezeichners mit dem auf dem PC angezeigten Bezeichnerwert.

Bezeichner:

    F85E6660-52A8-43D9-B66Z-F61246666666

Falls der obige Bezeichner mit dem auf dem PC angezeigten Bezeichner übereinstimmt, sollten Sie den folgenden Schlüssel zum Entsperren des Laufwerks verwenden.

Wiederherstellungsschlüssel:

    222222-333333-444444-555555-666666-777777-888888-999999

Falls der obige Bezeichner nicht mit dem auf dem PC angezeigten Bezeichner übereinstimmt, handelt es sich nicht um den richtigen Schlüssel zum Entsperren des Laufwerks.
Versuchen Sie es mit einem anderen Wiederherstellungsschlüssel, oder suchen Sie unter "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=qwerty" nach weiteren Informationen.

My Expression for the identifier:
id_expr = "\t[A-Z][0-9]-"

Expression for the key:
key_expr = "\t[0-9]-"

But they do not work.
The whole function looks like this:
import re

def extract_bitlocker_info(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()

    identifier_pattern = "\t[A-Z][0-9]-"
    identifier_match = re.search(identifier_pattern, content)
    identifier = identifier_match.group(1) if identifier_match else None

    recovery_key_pattern = "\t[0-9]-"
    recovery_key_match = re.search(recovery_key_pattern, content)
    recovery_key = recovery_key_match.group(1) if recovery_key_match else None

    return identifier, recovery_key



Like identifier_pattern =  r"\t[A-Z][0-9][A-Z0-9]*-[A-Z0-9-]+" and recovery_key_pattern = r"\t[0-9][0-9]*-[0-9-]+"

The regex pattern you entered matches the following examples:

\a1-
\B2-
\ta1-
\tB2-

They will not match these keys:

F85E6660-52A8-43D9-B66Z-F61246666666
222222-333333-444444-555555-666666-777777-888888-999999

To match the keys
update your regex patterns to this:
# Regular expression for the Identifier (Bezeichner)
identifier_pattern = r"[A-Z0-9]{8}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{12}"


# Regular expression for the Recovery Key (Wiederherstellungsschlüssel)
recovery_key_pattern = r"[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}"

You also need to update .group() method. group(0) returns the entire string matched by the regular expression
identifier = identifier_match.group(0)
recovery_key = recovery_key_match.group(0)


Could you provide an explaination WHY your pattern works, so that OP can learn from your solution and people who have similar issues in the future also?

Thank you for your reply! The regex works, but only when the content of the file is in a multiline string, however it does not work from the read()-string? What could be the reason for that? @Xenms

You could use a more recursive way to read the files. Using readlines() instead which returns a list of every line. You can then use a for loop to compare every line one by one.
import re

def extract_bitlocker_info(file_path):
    identifier = None
    recovery_key = None

    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        content = file.readlines()

    for line in content:

        identifier_pattern = r"[A-Z0-9]{8}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{12}"
        identifier_match = re.search(identifier_pattern, line)

        if identifier_match:
            identifier = identifier_match.group(0)

        recovery_key_pattern = r"[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}"
        recovery_key_match = re.search(recovery_key_pattern, line)

        if recovery_key_match:
            recovery_key = recovery_key_match.group(0)


    return identifier, recovery_key

Alternatively, if you really need the file to be in a single string. Replace all the newline characters "\n" with an empty string using a while loop checking if any "\n" remain.
import re

def strip_lines(text):
    while "\n" in text:
        text = text.replace("\n", "")
        text = text.replace(" ", "")
    return text


def extract_bitlocker_info(file_path):

    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()

        striped_content = strip_lines(content)

In reply to @DuesserBaest
The regex pattern [A-Z0-9]{8}- will match any alphanumeric characters (Uppercase letter and digit) A-Z and 0-9.
The square brackets [ ] define the range of characters it can match.
The curly braces { } indicate that the preceding character class (the combination of uppercase letters and digits) should repeat exactly 8 times.
You can use online tools like regex101.com to test your regex patterns and cheatography.com cheat sheet by DaveChild to learn the basics.
